# Operating system for Raspberry Pi

Tags: operating-systems

I have Raspberry Pi which needs to read sensor data through Bluetooth and I2C. I want to know the Linux operating system which will be well suited for this application.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the OS's available for the Pi would be able to meet your requirements. However, as it appears from your question that you are fairly new to the Pi I would suggest Raspbian which is based on Debian. You can download it from [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/). The main reason for this suggestion is that there are simply more tutorials and a bigger user base running Raspbian than the other OS's. This will make it easier to find code samples and get help when you run into problems. I would also suggest downloading the full (not lite) version as it includes the GUI making some tasks easier.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you tell the other OS that are available for raspberry pi

Comment: If you look to the left you will see related questions including this one http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/534/definitive-list-of-operating-systems?rq=1

Comment: Does Nard SDK will be suitable for my apllication???

Comment: I have no experience with it, but unless you are already familiar with it; you will have an easier time with Raspbian.