# How to setup raspberry pi 3?

Tags: software-installation

Please suggest me in installing raspberry pi operating system without using display i.e installation through ssh

Comment: How did all the methods suggested by Google fail?  Give details of every method you have used with detail of the steps at which it went wrong.

Comment: I dont have extra monitor display so i need to install raspberry pi operating by connecting ssh through ip address

Comment: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/15192/installing-raspbian-from-noobs-without-display Duplicate?

Comment: @kemis The answer you linked was for NOOBS, not Raspbian, and **NO LONGER WORKS**

Comment: This question is just too broad. There are *at least* a [couple of dozen available operating systems for the Pi](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/534/definitive-list-of-operating-systems), each of which will have different requirements for headless installations. If you can edit your question to specify a particular OS, and the steps you've already taken to try and get it set up, I'd be happy to reopen the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it depends on the operating system that you would like to install on the Raspberry pi, you have following options as far as I know, which you dont need SSH to install operating system:

1. Windows 10 IOT : https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot
2. Max2Play, Raspbian based operating system: https://www.max2play.com/en/
3. Raspbian: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/

Regards,

Mohammad Mbydeen

Comment: This is fine as it goes, but the overly-broad nature of the question makes this a fairly incomplete answer - there are a *great* many more than two options available for headless OS installations, including Raspbian. Given that Raspbian is likely to be the default OS of choice for the vast majority of Pi users I'd say it's a little disingenuous to leave it off the list here.