# what's the best os for the first gen 256mb pi?

Tags: operating-systems

what's the best os for the first gen 256mb pi?

i have one laying about and raspbian is using to much ram

any ideas?

Comment: Tried Raspbian Lite? Problem with this question that 'best' is very much a matter of opinion and that type of question is not really suited for SE.

Comment: You might like to look at the [Definitive List of Operating Systems](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/534/58316) on the site; asking for the "best" is probably, as Dirk noted, not ideal for this site. Be sure to read the [tour] for more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks dirk raspbian lite works great on the 256mb pi