# Cannot find Arch Linux .img download

Tags: archlinux

I wanted to burn the .img for Arch Linux ARMv6 to my Rasp Pi, but it seems that downloadable images can no longer be found. I followed instructions for sd card creation on the archlinuxARM site, as root, but `wget http://archlinuxarm.org/os/ArchLinuxARM-rpi-latest.tar.gz` only brought a series of "not found" messages...

Comment: I get a download for that link.  Where are you?

Comment: related: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/19/how-do-i-install-arch-linux/29451#29451 ... Please provide more details on "series of error messages" (or have this closed as a dupe).

Comment: I tried again, and this time it worked without error! Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4):

Arch Linux does not provide images anymore. Instead the .tar.gz will "simply" contain the full file system and has to be installed to the SD card after preparation of the partition table using `fdisk` and creation of the file systems `mkfs`. These steps are followed by copying the files from the .tar.gz to the root and boot file system.

Documentation of the full installation procedures:

- [Raspberry Pi](http://archlinuxarm.org/platforms/armv6/raspberry-pi)
- [Raspberry Pi 2](http://archlinuxarm.org/platforms/armv7/broadcom/raspberry-pi-2#qt-platform_tabs-ui-tabs2)

Comment: There's .IMG files for Arch on sourceforge https://sourceforge.net/projects/archlinux-rpi2/

Comment: @MikeRedrobe nice find, thanks. If you like you can post an additional answer which is preferable to a comment. Edit: Strike "nice find" and read "thanks for maintaining" instead ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Arch Linux themselves only provide a .tar.gz.

If you want an easy .IMG to burn to and SD card using Etcher or Win32diskimager,
here are .IMG files on sourceforge for the various Pi models:

- [Raspberry Pi Zero](https://sourceforge.net/projects/archlinuxrpi/)
- [Raspberry Pi 2 and 3](https://sourceforge.net/projects/archlinux-rpi2/)
- [Raspberry Pi 4](https://sourceforge.net/projects/archlinux-pi4/)