# Which Raspberry operating systems are there as SD card image?

Tags: operating-systems

Which Raspberry operating systems are available for download as an SD card image and what size should the SD card have to run it?

Related: [Definitive list of OS](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/534/definitive-list-of-operating-systems), but I want ready to use SD card images only.

Comment: How is this different from http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/534/definitive-list-of-operating-systems?noredirect=1&lq=1? Instead of turning this into a second highly related question, why can't you edit the other question and add the SD card details to that question's answers. Not to mention it would be shorter to go the other (list the non SD card images)way as almost all are SD card images.

Comment: Having too largely identical questions that are intended to be canonical will quickly dissolve into a divergent mess. Your criteria of an SD card image adds little as most of them are distributed that way. As I said above you would be better off listing the ones that don't and adding that info to the other question.

Answer (score 2):

### Noobs

[Download](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/noobs/)

Is actually an operating system installer, not an OS itself.

### [Raspbian](https://www.raspbian.org/)

Official [download](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/).

A Debian derivative. Available as a normal version (4 GB card needed) and Lite version (512 MB).

### [Ubuntu Mate](https://ubuntu-mate.org/)

[Download](https://ubuntu-mate.org/download/)

Based on Ubuntu.

### [ArchLinux](https://www.archlinux.org/)

[Download](http://downloads.raspberrypi.org/arch/images/)

Lightweight Linux distribution. Images are no longer maintained for Raspberry. Installation is done from tarballs now with manual setup of partitions and file systems, see [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/29451/19949).

### [Pidora](http://pidora.ca/)

[Direct download](http://pidora.ca/pidora/releases/20/images/Pidora-2014-R3.zip)

Fedora based. No longer maintained. For Raspberry Pi 1 only.

### [Fedberry](http://fedberry.org/)

[Download](http://fedberry.org/#download)

Fedora based. Raspberry 2 and 3.

### [OpenWrt](https://openwrt.org/)

[Download](https://downloads.openwrt.org/chaos_calmer/15.05.1/brcm2708/)

A small operating system focusing on network connectivity.

Download `openwrt-brcm2708-bcm2708-sdcard-vfat-ext4.img` for Raspberry Pi 1.

Download `openwrt-brcm2708-bcm2709-sdcard-vfat-ext4.img` for Raspberry Pi 2/3

### [OSMC](https://osmc.tv/) (formerly RaspBMC)

[Download](https://osmc.tv/download/)

Open source media center.

### Windows 10 IoT Core

[Download](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/downloads)

Can run Universal .NET Core apps.

### [RetroPie](https://retropie.org.uk/)

[Download](https://retropie.org.uk/download/)

Turns your Pi into an arcade station.

### [RISCOS](https://www.riscosopen.org/)

[Download](https://www.riscosopen.org/content/downloads/raspberry-pi) (2 GB card needed)

OS running with small CPU and memory footprint. Is not a Linux derivative.

### Plan 9

[Direct download](http://plan9.bell-labs.com/sources/contrib/miller/9pi.img.gz)

Experimental Unix clone. Read the [Newbie Guide](http://www.quanstro.net/newbie-guide.pdf), e.g. to know that the <kbd>Del</kbd> key kills programs.

### [OpenELEC](http://openelec.tv/)

[Download for Pi 1](http://openelec.tv/get-openelec/category/6-raspberry-pi-builds), [Download for Pi 2](http://openelec.tv/get-openelec/category/7-raspberry-pi2-builds)

### [RaspBSD](http://raspbsd.org/)

[Download](http://raspbsd.org/raspberrypi.html)

Based on FreeBSD 11.

### [Nard SDK](http://www.arbetsmyra.dyndns.org/nard/)

[Download](http://www.arbetsmyra.dyndns.org/nard/download/nard-sdcard.img.zip) (16 MB card min, 1GB recommended)

For embedded systems, a robust in-RAM only distro.

Comment: This is intended to be a canonical answer. Please edit it.